# Lenovo laptop does not shutdown if anything is connected via USB

Tags: usb, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Thinkcentre A52. If I have any device (even a USB cord) plugged into my USB sockets, the computer just restarts when I ask it to shutdown. If I remove everything from the USB sockets it shuts down normally.

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: My best guess is that Power on USB is enabled in the BIOS